# android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.RelativeLayout

Tags: android

My app keeps crashing on launch, with this error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout cannot be cast to
>   android.widget.RelativeLayout.

I can't seem to work out what to do with my `xml` file as I've tried changing the `ConstraintLayout` tag to `RelativeLayout`.

Here's my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_send"
        android:tint="@android:color/white"
        app:fabSize="mini"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"></android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="284dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="284dp"
        android:hint="Message..."
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_of_message"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/fab"
        android:dividerHeight="16dp"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></ListView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I think you are trying
 `Relativelayout = findViewById(R.id.activity_main);`
but Now after editing it is `ConstraintLayout = findViewById(R.id.activity_main);`

Comment: Would you please provide your java code.

Comment: The problem was in the java code @FaysalAhmed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your java file change

```
Relativelayout layout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
```

To

```
Relativelayout layout = (Relativelayout ) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
```

That will fix your problem. you change XML but don't change java bind.

Answer (score 1):

You can't Cast Relativelayout with ConstraintLayout so for that you have to Cast it with the same class name which is in XML like this

```
Relativelayout layout = (Relativelayout ) findViewById(R.id.layout);
```